# DigitalOcean Ubuntu + Docker how to expose node_exporter 9100 port?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am a novice in docker/unix. Configured docker and container and also, i need to collect metrics for outer prometheus server, so i installed node_exporter there. I was surprised, that i can't access metrics by following :9100/metrics url. I tried the same on ubuntu without docker - works fine.

Do you have any suggestions why it may happen?

Answer (score 0):

All i found is to reset iptables by this command :

```
sudo ufw reset
```

And it helps! You just need to re-run daemon after this. Be carefully in case if you need to proxy outer connections to docker - so i think it will loose this functionality after this command, but for my purposes it is perfect.